# Properly using Anaconda's Python as the PATH's "python"

Tags: python, environment-variables, anaconda, command-prompt

I've noticed that while I can point my environment variables to Anaconda's Python interpreter, I don't get a fully working Python environment when I execute `python` in the command prompt. Python will still launch, but many of its packages are "broken."

**PROBLEM:**

Anaconda's Python interpreter does launch when called from command prompt, but it isn't able to import some of its packages (numpy being one of them used in this example).

**EXAMPLE(WINDOWS CMD):**

```
> where python
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

Great, `python` calls the right interpreter. Let's go in there and `import numpy`!

```
> python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

This is weird. Let's try launching "Anaconda Prompt", which appears to just be an *activated* Anaconda environment.

```
>python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

Everything works fine this way.

**SUMMARY:**

I'm expecting Anaconda's Python interpreter to launch from the command prompt and behave just the way it would if launched from within the Anaconda Prompt (which appears to just be a command prompt with an *activated* Anaconda environment).

What can I do to be able to get a fully working Anaconda Python interpreter by just launching `python` from the Window's command prompt? Maybe what I'm really asking is, what do I need to change in my environment variables to ensure that the Anaconda environment is activated when I call on `python` from the command prompt?

Comment: Activating a conda environment can also change the PATH. I suggest you compare PATH before and after activating the environment.

Comment: @codeape good call. I checked, and it appears that Anaconda inserts a total of 6 (4 more than the Anaconda3 and Anaconda3/Scripts folder that I have added myself).

Comment: OK so does ``import numpy`` now work from an un-activated ``python.exe`` if you set correct PATH first?

IIRC, this is one of the cases where anaconda has patched the core python interpreter for some reason (the stock python.org python does not have this problem).

Comment: @codeape Yup. If you want to post an answer about the activated environment adding new PATH variables, I'll accept as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activating a conda environment can also change the PATH. I suggest you compare PATH before and after activating the environment.